# Read tool tip message from system tray

Tags: c#

Is there any code to read tooltip from icon in system tray ? I need to know the status of application and the only one to know this application running is it's tooltip.

Thank you

Comment: Why not just check if the program is running in processes?

Comment: this application connecting to PABX system. if both system are connected, the application will write the status in it's tooltip. The application still running whenever disconnected from PABX system.

Answer (score 0):

This really doesn't seem to be a very good idea and would be very specific to the O/S the app is running under and the version of the app, ie. different versions of the app might display a different tool tip. Far better to contact the app vendor (if possible) and determine a better way to tell the apps current status, e.g. via web service "health check" call.

However it does seem possible, per the following API call:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760751(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I am sorry, my Server using windows 2008 R2, but the application that i want to check is running under 32 bit. In my opinion, it better if i use .NET framework cause windows is running under 64 bit